# How to disable autocommit in sqlite4java?

Tags: java, sqlite

I have recently been playing with the sqlite4java library.
I think I have it pretty much figured out. The only think that bothers me is that I do not know how to switch off the auto-commit using this library. Can anyone please help?
A code example would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Boro

Comment: I haven't used java sqlite, but with the canonical C implementation, if you [begin a transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), it disabled auto-commit. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a read, but still I couldn't figure out how to do it using the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jefromi and king_nak are correct - you just need to issue SQL statements that begin and end a transaction.

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection();
con.exec("BEGIN");
// do transaction work - auto-commit is disabled
con.exec("COMMIT");
// auto-commit is enabled again
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for the answer. I understand it now. Thanks for the clear code example.

Comment: I think you can set PRAGMA synchronous off (without using the begin/commit transactions) but its only on a per-connection basis and so if you have a connection pool you need to set it on each connection.  Its quite messy compared to the above example.

Comment: @djangofan pragma synchronous off has nothing to do with the auto-commit

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I confused sqlite4java with the sqliteJDBC package. So the below code will not help. I'm keeping it for reference nevertheless.

After you obtained the connection, just call `setAutoCommit(false)`

```
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/your/db/file", "user", "password");
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: Yea I see what you mean, but I wonder how to do it in this particular library (sqlite4java). Using this I do not know how to then cast it to SQLiteConnection. Thanks.

Comment: This is standard JDBC code and will run with every JDBC driver (that supports autocommit). There is no need to cast this to a specific type of connection class.

Comment: sqlite4java is no JDBC driver... its a wrapper for SQLite's C interface

Comment: @king_nak: Ah, I thought that was the JDBC driver for SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [SQLite's C interface description](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html):

> The sqlite3_get_autocommit() interface returns non-zero or zero if the given database connection is or is not in autocommit mode, respectively. Autocommit mode is on by default. Autocommit mode is disabled by a BEGIN statement. Autocommit mode is re-enabled by a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

So you disable auto-commit by a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement. No separate API function is present for this

Comment: Just discovered that Jefromi has already posted this in a comment to the question.