# Clarification of Java/SQLite batch and auto-commit

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I copied the following example from an SQLite Java library website:

```
PreparedStatement prep =
         conn.prepareStatement("insert into people values (?, ?);");
prep.setString(1, "Gandhi");
prep.setString(2, "politics");
prep.addBatch();
prep.setString(1, "Turing");
prep.setString(2, "computers");
prep.addBatch();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
prep.executeBatch();
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

I'm struggling to understand the significance of toggling `autoCommit()` either side of `executeBatch()`.  Does it merely prevent a commit being made for each individual batch operation?  Thus a single 'bulk' commit is will be made by `setAutoCommit(true)`.

Comment: I've added an answer to this that contradicts some of the information in the accepted answer.  FYI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The auto commit is disabled before batch because enabling auto commit will commit (i.e. wait for sync to happen which means it will wait the data is actually written to persistent storage like hard disk) after every row that is inserted.

If auto commit is false, it will not wait for sync.

The difference in waiting for sync and not waiting is the guaranty that whether data is actually to hard disk or it is in the buffer (that could be buffered IO or buffer of hard disk).

**In short, disabling auto commit gives you performance boost.** And I think by default auto commit is enabled.

**Another way of optimization**

If you want to have auto commit ON and still need performance boost just try to start as transaction before the batch operation and commit the transaction after. This way sqlite wont auto commit after every insert and **it will give good performance boost.**

EDIT:

When you starting a transaction you are only disabling auto commit
for that transaction and it will be again 'on' once transaction is over. What auto commit helps is
when you are inserting/updating rows separately (not as batch), then you dont have to start a
transaction explicitly for every insert/update. And regarding setting auto-commit to true, after the
fact, does not do call for commit. If you make auto-commit
true and whatever you have already inserted/updated wont have any effect and won't have same
guaranties as auto-commit true prior to making those insert/update.

[Here's some information about speeding up Sqlite INSERTs.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  You're correct, `autoCommit()` is enabled by default.  When `autoCommit(true)` is called, do you know if the batch data will be written to persistent storage?

Comment: yes it will be written. It wont have the same guaranty as with auto commit on. I had updated my ans to give you another option.

Answer (score 4):

There has been some wrong information shared in the answers and comments here so I'd thought I'd add an answer.

1. FYI, SQLite does not support auto-commit directly.  Calling `setAutoCommit(false)` on a SQLite JDBC connection actually starts a transaction with the Xerial and Zentus drivers.   See this SO question: [How to disable autocommit in sqlite4java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998630/how-to-disable-autocommit-in-sqlite4java)
2. I'm almost positive that setting auto-commit back to true will *not* do a commit on the database connection. The next statement that finishes will persist any outstanding changes but you have to do a `conn.commit();` to actually commit the batch operations.
3. Starting a transaction basically is the same as turning off auto-commit so it is improper to imply that you can leave auto-commit on while inside of a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your input Mr Gray!  I'm still confused why the code [here](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) would suggest using `setAutoCommit(...)`, as per my original post.  Also, how would `conn.exec("COMMIT")` and `conn.commit()` compare?  Does the latter essentially 'wrap' the former? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the Zentus driver is doing a transaction under the covers.  BTW, the Xerial Sqlite driver is vastly superior to the Zentus.  http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC

Comment: RE: `conn.exec("COMMIT")`, right, duh, I've changed that to `conn.commit()`.

Comment: The Zentus driver does the following in `setAutoCommit(...)`: `db.exec(autoCommit ? "commit;" : "begin;");` so it does use a transaction under the covers.  Maybe the Xerial driver does the same as well.

Comment: Yes, the Xerial driver seem to do the same.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @havexz THe part about being able to keep auto-commit on true and starting transaction.  In Sqlite, if you are starting a transaction you are doing the same thing as setting auto-commit to false.  Also although it works with the Zentus and Xerial drivers, there is nothing about setting auto-commit to true that actually does a `commit`.  Certainly bad practice.

Comment: @Gray since..there is a limit on the number of characters I can write in the comment. I have to update my ans...

Comment: No problem @havexz.  I've removed the conversation stuff out of your answer.  It is in your comments below your answer where you say that `autoCommit(true)` commits.  Although correct with JDBC Sqlite implementations, this is not the way JDBC typically works.  FYI.

Answer (score 0):

What does works with me is to set the follwing:

```
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
        ps1.executeUpdate();
        ps2.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Comment: Kindly explain in detail what is the question. Wat you are trying to do and where you are getting stuck